# How to filter rows based on difference in dates between rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Within each `id`, I would like to keep rows that are at least 91 days apart. In my dataframe `df` below, `id=1` has 5 rows and `id=2` has 1 row.

For `id=1`, I would like to keep only the 1st, 3rd and 5th rows.

This is because if we compare 1st date and 2nd date, they differ by 32 days. So, remove 2nd date. We proceed to comparing 1st and 3rd date, and they differ by 152 days. So, we keep 3rd date.

Now, instead of using 1st date as reference, we use 3rd date. 3rd date and 4th date differ by 61 days. So, remove 4th date. We proceed to comparing 3rd date and 5th date, and they differ by 121 days. So, we keep 5th date.

In the end, the dates we keep are 1st, 3rd and 5th dates. As for `id=2`, there is only one row, so we keep that. The desired result is shown in `dfnew`.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  var1  date        
 1  A     2006-01-01 
 1  B     2006-02-02 
 1  C     2006-06-02 
 1  D     2006-08-02 
 1  E     2007-12-01 
 2  F     2007-04-20 
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dfnew <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  var1  date        
 1  A     2006-01-01 
 1  C     2006-06-02 
 1  E     2007-12-01 
 2  F     2007-04-20 
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I can only think of starting with grouping the `df` by `id` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
dfnew <- df %>% group_by(id)
```

However, I am not sure of how to continue from here. Should I proceed with `filter` function or `slice`? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative that uses `slice` from `dplyr` is to define the following recursive function:

```
library(dplyr)
f <- function(d, ind=1) {
  ind.next <- first(which(difftime(d,d[ind], units="days") > 90))
  if (is.na(ind.next))
    return(ind)
  else
    return(c(ind, f(d,ind.next)))
}
```

This function operates on the `date` column starting at `ind = 1`. It then finds the next index `ind.next` that is the `first` index for which the date is greater than 90 days (at least 91 days) from the date indexed by `ind`. Note that if there is no such `ind.next`, `ind.next==NA` and we just return `ind`. Otherwise, we recursively call `f` starting at `ind.next` and return its result concatenated with `ind`. The end result of this function call are the row indices separated by at least 91 days.

With this function, we can do:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(f(as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")))
##Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
##Groups: id [2]
##
##     id  var1       date
##  <int> <chr>      <chr>
##1     1     A 2006-01-01
##2     1     C 2006-06-02
##3     1     E 2007-12-01
##4     2     F 2007-04-20
```

The use of this function assumes that the `date` column is sorted in ascending order by each `id` group. If not, we can just sort the dates before slicing. Not sure about the efficiency of this or the dangers of recursive calls in R. Hopefully, David Arenburg or others can comment on this.

---

As suggested by David Arenburg, it is better to convert `date` to a Date class first instead of by group:

```
result <- df %>% mutate(date=as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
                 group_by(id) %>% slice(f(date))
##Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
##Groups: id [2]
##
##     id  var1       date
##  <int> <chr>     <date>
##1     1     A 2006-01-01
##2     1     C 2006-06-02
##3     1     E 2007-12-01
##4     2     F 2007-04-20
```

Comment: Maybe convert to a `Date` class first instead of doing it by group

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thank you, your comments are always greatly appreciated. I made the edit.

Comment: Hi @aichao this answer helps a lot. I have a dataset which I would like to filter rows such that the dates are 365 days apart (+/- 90 days) from the previous ones. This date must be the nearest to the 365th-day mark. I have adapted your code as follows: `f <- function(d, ind = 1) {
  datediff <- difftime(d, d[ind], units = "days")
  ind.range <- which(datediff >= 275 & datediff <= 455)
  ind.min <- which.min(abs(datediff - 365))
  ind.next <- first(intersect(ind.range, ind.min))

  if (is.na(ind.next))
    return(ind)
  else
    return(c(ind, f(d, ind.next)))
}` Is this okay?

Comment: Need to arrange first before slicing

Answer (score 14):

Here's an attempt using rolling joins in the `data.table` which I believe should be efficient

```
library(data.table)
# Set minimum distance
mindist <- 91L 
# Make sure it is a real Date
setDT(df)[, date := as.IDate(date)] 
# Create a new column with distance + 1 to roll join too
df[, date2 := date - (mindist + 1L)] 
# Perform a rolling join per each value in df$date2 that has atleast 91 difference from df$date
unique(df[df, on = c(id = "id", date = "date2"), roll = -Inf], by = c("id", "var1"))
#    id var1       date      date2 i.var1     i.date
# 1:  1    A 2005-10-01 2005-10-01      A 2006-01-01
# 2:  1    C 2006-03-02 2006-03-02      C 2006-06-02
# 3:  1    E 2007-08-31 2007-08-31      E 2007-12-01
# 4:  2    F 2007-01-18 2007-01-18      F 2007-04-20
```

This will give you two additional columns but it's not a big of a deal IMO. Logically this makes sense and I've tested it successfully on different scenarios but it may need some additional proof tests.