# Code to include/exclude patients in a R dataset

Tags: r, filter, dataset

In my dataset in r, i only want the same patient to appears ones within 30 days.
The patients can appear multiple times  within week, month, year.
I just don't want them to appear twice within 30 days.
My dataset is very large, so difficult to check if the code is correct.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Amanda Marie Egeskov-Cavling! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Does it matter which records are kept if they overlap in a 30-day window?  For example, what is the desired output for a patient appearing on the 1st, 15th and 31st of January?  There are a number of valid outputs under your 30 day criteria that are maximal in the sense that no other values could be added: 1) 1st and 31st (assuming they can only appear once with any 30 day window); 2) 15th.

Comment: In addition to the above, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317354/how-to-filter-rows-based-on-difference-in-dates-between-rows-in-r) on removing rows based on difference between dates may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a data.table implementation which will identify and remove records which appear within 30 days of another with the same ID.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(collapse)

# Randomly generate 1,000 people with 5% chance of appointments on a given day
N <- 1000
p <- 0.05

set.seed(6453)
dt <- lapply(seq(ymd('2024-01-01'), ymd('2024-12-31'), by = '1 day'),
       function (x) data.table(id = (1:N)[runif(N) < p], day = x)) %>%
  rbindlist()
setorder(dt, id, day)

dt[, day_diff := as.numeric(day - L(day, g = id))]
dt[is.na(day_diff), day_diff := 0]
dt[, cum_diff := cumsum(day_diff), by = .(id)]

# Leave anything within 30 days, reset on > 30 days and repeat.
while(max(dt$cum_diff) > 30){
  dt[cum_diff > 30, cum_diff := cum_diff - min(cum_diff), by = .(id)]
}
# Keep the ones equal to 0, drop the rest as they are within 30 days.
keep <- dt[cum_diff == 0]

# Check it meets requirements
setorder(keep, id, day)
keep[, day_diff := as.numeric(day - L(day, g = id))] 
keep[, cum_diff := NULL]
nrow(keep[day_diff <= 30]) # = 0
```